# EWS Search Appointments by Subject

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS Managed API 2.0.  I would like to be able to search a calendar in exchange on the subject of the appointment in the future.

The caveats are:

1. only return future appointments matching the subject="test"
2. only return future appointments in the next 90 days

I can get CalendarView to return appointments in the next 90 days, but cannot figure out how to filter using a SearchFilter.  For best performance, I'd rather not return all appointments and then filter.

I can filter the appointments by Subject using ItemView and a SearchFilter.  However this doesn't filter out appointments that have already occurred.  It returns everything matching the filter.

Ideally, it would be nice if I could use a CalendarView in the SearchFilter but I receive the error **"Restrictions and sort order may not be specified for a CalendarView."**

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = svc().FindItems(fId, filter, cView);
```

Any help would be great... thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out....

Using compound search filters, like so

```
        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection coll = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);            
        SearchFilter subjectFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(AppointmentSchema.Subject, "test");
        SearchFilter dateFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Today);
        coll.Add(subjectFilter);
        coll.Add(dateFilter);

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = svc().FindItems(fId, coll, view);
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware, when using compound search filters you will not get occurrences of a recurring series if the master element is outside of the specified time range.

This is because occurrences (and exceptions) in a recurring series are not actual items in the mailbox, but rather are stored internally as attachments to a recurring master. 
The *ExchangeService.FindItems* method does not look through the attachment table of every calendar item to find occurrences and exceptions. (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_recurring)

So if you're dealing with recurring events you're (IMHO) better off using a CalendarView and the *CalendarFolder.FindAppointments* method, which performs recurrence expansion for recurring appointments.

The downside is that it does not support search filters... So you must filter subjects seperately.

Does anybody have a better solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.